# Firebase Cloud Functions Simply Refuse to Read From Realtime Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createNewGame = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        var database = admin.database();

        database.ref().on('value', function(data) {
                console.log('SOMETHING');
        });

        response.end();
});
```

The problem is, it is not logging "SOMETHING". It is as if it is refusing to call the "on" function. It logs that the function was called and that it was executed successfully, however, it does not actually run anything inside the callback function in "on".

Any help is appreciated, I have no idea what else to try to get this to run, I have literally copy-pasted code from Firebase's documentation to no avail.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the response before the database read from the database. This likely terminates the function before the log statement can execute.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createNewGame = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    var database = admin.database();

    database.ref().once('value', function(data) {
        console.log('SOMETHING');
        response.end();
    });

});
```

Note that I also changed `on()` to `once()`, since you're only interested in receiving the current value.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! This thing is still giving me problems as apparently it's setting the header after the response is set but such is the life of a programmer...